# grunt server error - unable to create directory

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I use grunt with yeoman, and I got this error. Now
I can ignore this warning with `--force` but it feels uncomfortable.

```
kim@ubuntu:~/testApp$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Warning: Unable to create directory "/home/kim/testApp/.tmp" (Error code: EACCES). Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2015-01-20 11:25:22 UTC)
    loading tasks  3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 25%
    copy:styles    9ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 75%
    Total 12ms Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-01-20 11:25:20 UTC)
concurrent:server  1.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
Total 1.9s

kim@ubuntu:~/testApp$
```

Comment: This is probably due to you not having write access to /home/kim/testApp/.tmp directory whcih concurrent task is using for temporary files...

Answer (score 0):

"/home/kim/testApp/.tmp" path is relative, so it may be trying to create this path starting on your computers root, if you are in a Mac, that's Macintosh HD and grunt doesn't have write access to root.

Unless of course you run grunt command with sudo from Terminal, in that case it will create the path in root which isn't what you are looking for.

The --force command shouldn't be doing anything here, it just skips the warning and continue with the remaining tasks but it won't create the directory.

Try changing your relative path to an Absolute path, something like:
"/Users/YourUserFolderName/..complete path to your folder here../home/kim/testApp/.tmp"

I noticed you're on ubuntu but it may be the same problem.